# HTML,CSS checkbox label position should be on top of checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

good day, I am not good at CSS and I am getting a hard time to position the checkbox label on top of checkbox itself. Can you please help me? I want it the label also to be center formatted text because I want also to change the text dynamically using jquery. If I checked it, the "Fix" text will become "Fixed" and this text should remain its centered position on the top of the checkbox. Here is my JSFIDDLE >>> https://jsfiddle.net/koykoys/d2cb96xo/ .

**Note: Please do not modify the "html" part, only the "css" part.

Thank you.

```css
input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked),
input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label,
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label{
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* checkbox aspect */
input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:before,
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left:0; top: 2px;
  width: 40px; height: 40px;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 2px solid #aaa;
  -webkit-box-shadow: groove 0 0 13px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: groove 0 0 13px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
/* checked mark aspect */
input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:after,
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
  content: '✔';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 5px;
  font-size: 34px;
  color: green;
  transition: all .2s;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s;
  -moz-transition: all .2s;
  -ms-transition: all .2s;
  -o-transition: all .2s;
}
/* checked mark aspect changes */
input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:after {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
   <input id="checkid"  type="checkbox">
   <label for="checkid">Fixed</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will center the label above the "checkbox" (which is no longer actually an `input type="checkbox"` since you are using pseudo elements on the label to visually replace it).

```css
input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked),
input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label,
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label{
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}


/* checkbox aspect */
input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:before,
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left:50%; top: 20px;
  width: 40px; height: 40px;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 2px solid #aaa;
  -webkit-box-shadow: groove 0 0 13px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: groove 0 0 13px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
/* checked mark aspect */
input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:after,
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
  content: '✔';
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px; left: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 34px;
  color: green;
  transition: all .2s;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s;
  -moz-transition: all .2s;
  -ms-transition: all .2s;
  -o-transition: all .2s;
  text-align: center;
}
/* checked mark aspect changes */
input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:after {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
   <input id="checkid"  type="checkbox">
   <label for="checkid">Fixed</label>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12">
   <input id="checkid2"  type="checkbox">
   <label for="checkid2">Label can now vary in length</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @connexo , this is what I am looking for :) , I hope I can become as talented as you when it comes to css. :)

Answer (score 2):

Simply do with some alignments remove padding and adjust position

```css
input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked), input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
 position: absolute;
 left: -9999px;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label, input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
 position: relative;
 cursor: pointer;
}
/* checkbox aspect */
input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:before, input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 22px;
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 background: #f8f8f8;
 border-radius: 3px;
 border: 2px solid #aaa;
 -webkit-box-shadow: groove 0 0 13px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 box-shadow: groove 0 0 13px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
/* checked mark aspect */
input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:after, input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
 content: '✔';
 position: absolute;
 top: 16px;
 left: 10px;
 font-size: 34px;
 color: green;
 transition: all .2s;
 -webkit-transition: all .2s;
 -moz-transition: all .2s;
 -ms-transition: all .2s;
 -o-transition: all .2s;
}
/* checked mark aspect changes */
input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:after {
 opacity: 0;
 transform: scale(0);
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
 opacity: 1;
 transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

</head>

<body>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <input id="checkid"  type="checkbox">
  <label for="checkid">Fixed</label>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: OP stated the requirement of having centered label text with regard to the checkbox.

Comment: Thank you, this is really a nice solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you actually want your `<label>` element on top of your checkbox (like your question states), and you're not instead wanting to vertically align your label's text like the other answers here are doing: Simply set your pseudo-elements to have a `top` property set to `100%` (which will place them directly below the `<label>` element), then give the `<label>` element some bottom `margin` to push any further elements down a little (to give space for the pseudo-elements), then set the `<label>` to `display` as *block*.

```css
input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked),
input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label,
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label{
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}


/* checkbox aspect */
input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:before,
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left:0; top: 100%;
  width: 40px; height: 40px;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 2px solid #aaa;
  -webkit-box-shadow: groove 0 0 13px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: groove 0 0 13px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
/* checked mark aspect */
input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:after,
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
  content: '✔';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%; left: 5px;
  font-size: 34px;
  color: green;
  transition: all .2s;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s;
  -moz-transition: all .2s;
  -ms-transition: all .2s;
  -o-transition: all .2s;
}
/* checked mark aspect changes */
input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:after {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
   <input id="checkid"  type="checkbox">
   <label for="checkid">Fixed</label>
</div>
```

Comment: OP stated the requirement of having centered label text with regard to the checkbox.

Comment: @connexo they did indeed, which is why I've already upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I added a `margin-top: 50px` to force the box down and give a room for the label. Here's the complete CSS, I din't edit your original code I only added some lines. I wrote comments to the lines I added.

```
input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked),
input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
  /* added */
  opacity: 0;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label,
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label{
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* added */
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 4px;
}


/* checkbox aspect */
input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:before,
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left:0; top: 2px;
  width: 40px; height: 40px;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 2px solid #aaa;
  -webkit-box-shadow: groove 0 0 13px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: groove 0 0 13px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  /* added */
  margin-top: 20px;
}
/* checked mark aspect */
input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:after,
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
  content: '✔';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 5px;
  font-size: 34px;
  color: green;
  transition: all .2s;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s;
  -moz-transition: all .2s;
  -ms-transition: all .2s;
  -o-transition: all .2s;
  /* added */
  margin-top: 20px;
}
/* checked mark aspect changes */
input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:after {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Why Dont You Try something Simple....... Put your lableon top and  add just a "br"

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

     <form action="demo_form.asp" method="get"><lable>asdf</lable><br>
     <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"><br>

     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You may not have noticed that the checkbox you see is not the `input`, but a `::before` pseudo element on the label.

Answer (score -1):

Just add:

```
input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label,
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
    padding-top: 11px;
}
```